# How to use replace method for dollar sign and comma?

Tags: javascript, parsing, replace, reduce

I want to accomplish two things, parse the balances to be integers (i assume that is needed), then add up the total balances using reduce method. I don't know the best way to remove the comma though? or should I use splice instead?
If the reduce method adds them now, it only adds the first digit before the comma so 1,1,8.

```
const data = [{
    index: "14",
    name: "Bob",
    balance: "$1,000",
  },
  {
    index: "23",
    name: "John",
    balance: "$1,200",
  },
  {
    index: "17",
    name: "Steve",
    balance: "$8,000",
  },
];
```

```
const balances = data.map((amount) => {
  var newAmount = parseFloat(amount.balance.replace(/\$/g, ""));
  return newAmount;
});

console.log(balances);

const reducer = (accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue;
console.log(balances.reduce(reducer));
```

This will attempt to remove the $ and add up the balances and show them. However I cannot figure out how to remove the comma as well (which should fix it)?

Comment: You can use a character class: `/[$,]/g`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using **replace**

```js
const data = [
  {
    index: "14",
    name: "Bob",
    balance: "$1,000",
  },
  {
    index: "23",
    name: "John",
    balance: "$1,200",
  },
  {
    index: "17",
    name: "Steve",
    balance: "$8,000",
  },
];
const result = data
  .map((o) => parseFloat(o.balance.replace(/[$,]/g, "")))
  .reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr, 0);

console.log(result);
```

using **match**

```js
const data = [{
    index: "14",
    name: "Bob",
    balance: "$1,000",
  },
  {
    index: "23",
    name: "John",
    balance: "$1,200",
  },
  {
    index: "17",
    name: "Steve",
    balance: "$8,000",
  },
];

const result = data
  .map((o) => {
    return +o.balance.match(/[\d]+/g).join("");
  })
  .reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr, 0);

console.log(result);
```

or

```js
const data = [
  {
    index: "14",
    name: "Bob",
    balance: "$1,000",
  },
  {
    index: "23",
    name: "John",
    balance: "$1,200",
  },
  {
    index: "17",
    name: "Steve",
    balance: "$8,000",
  },
];

const result = data
  .map((o) => parseFloat(o.balance.match(/[\d]+/g).join("")))
  .reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr, 0);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `character class [$,]` which accept ANY ONE of the character within the square bracket.

```js
const getAmount = (amount) => {
  return parseFloat(amount.replace(/[$,]/g, ""));
}

console.log(getAmount("$123,45.132"));
```